# how do I trigger a /setblock command without a /testfor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In my map, the player goes to sleep, then wakes up and finds the windows are changed from regular panes to red ones stained with blood. But if I do `/testfor`, it will trigger whenever the player passes by, so that is not useful in this circumstance. **Is there a way to trigger a command block when you wake up?**

Comment: Heh @AngusAtkinson your always editing my posts :P

Comment: avoid using facial expressions and emojis in the posts, and use the backtick ( ` ) to denote that it is a code/command. Don't leave the posts for others to edit it for you.

Comment: Jeez I'm new to this, so sorry it doesn't come naturally @ArceusMaster0493

Comment: That's why I'm reminding you to do so ;)

Comment: @xXPikminXx Sorry, I'm not picking on you, I just like to edit posts by all users to make this site better.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson I know, I'm not mad, I just find it funny that you always are :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use testfor. Here's how it works - set up the device as you would with the testfor, but change the testfor to this command.

```
/testfor @a {Sleeping:1b}
```

Comment: Whenever I do that, it just says "xXPikminXx did not meet the requirements in the data structure" @132ikl

Comment: @xXPikminXx Do you a) have it running on a clock b) have 1b and not just 1

Comment: turns out I didnt have it on a running clock. thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to trigger something with redstone or use the /testfor command.

I would recommend testing for the exact block the player stands on when they wake up, as well as the exact time Minecraft warps to when the player wakes up. Realistically that would only occur is if they sleep in the specified bed you want them to.

Another thing you could try is testing for whether the [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) is occupied or not:

```
 /testforblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:bed -1 {occupied:true}
```

Comment: how would you test for if the bed was occupied or not?

Comment: /testforblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:bed -1 {occupied:true}